# Stop miss behavior of ul-li on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I hav a nav menu which has a white text and blue background and on hover its blue text with black background where as on `selected` its white text with black background.
 But if I hover on `selected menu item` it shows me blue text (properties of `:hover`) which I don't want to happen. Any way I can stop it?

**Fiddle :** [link](http://jsfiddle.net/WTeYW/)

Comment: Provide your code in the question, not just a link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `.selected:hover` case as well

```
main_menu li .selected,
main_menu li .selected:hover{
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/WTeYW/3/

---

Additionally, since your `.selected` and `:hover` rules are identical except for the color you should merge them and create new rules just for the differences (*better maintainability*)

```
.main_menu li a:hover,
.main_menu li a.selected{
    box-shadow:0 20px 30px -10px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-color:#888; 
    background:#000; 
}

.main_menu li a:hover{color:#6cf;}
.main_menu li a.selected,
.main_menu li a.selected:hover{color:#ffffff;}
```

Demo including this at http://jsfiddle.net/WTeYW/5/

---

(***notice :*** if you read the original answer it was a bit wrong. the `a.selected` is not more specific, it is equally specific but prevailed because it was the last in the CSS file. The above correction is the way to do it.)

Comment: thanks @Gaby aka G. Petrioli. first u had put `a.selected` den u changed it to `.selected:hover` does it make any difference in behavior.

Comment: @vishalkin, (*i have added in my answer a **notice** at the end about it.. also updated with another generic improvement*)

Answer (score 0):

I used CSS :not(.selected) to prevent :hover being executed.

```
.main_menu li a:not(.selected):hover{
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/CfeCB/

This is what you mean right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `:not()` selector for this :

```
.main_menu li a:hover:not(.selected){
    box-shadow:0 20px 30px -10px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-color:#888; 
    background:#000; 
    color:#6cf;
    }
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/WTeYW/4/)

[Refrence 1](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)